# Special character display along with their name in md-select

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I have md-select with the values from the database. The value having a name with special characters. I am using angularjs material.

Example: In database: Sathya & ram,

It displays like: Sathya &amp ram in md-option.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the value into a div with the directive `ng-bind-html` like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="$ctrl.name"></div>
```

This directive evaluated Html, so **use with care**

[Docs for ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

**EDIT**

I think you could also assign the directive to `md-option` directly.

Comment: Can you tell me, why should I use this ng-bind-html instead of angularjs expression {{}}

Comment: By default, expressions do not evaluate Html. I think you can evaluate Html in your controller with $sce, but I am not very familiar with it: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce